# fabric.js - text underline and lineHeight

Tags: javascript, fabricjs, textedit

I've added underline to the text in fabric.js, and it works as following image. But the underline is a bit far from the text, I changed `lineHeight` attribute, the underline could be more closer text, but the problem is the selection control height also changed too. See the pictures below.

This first one, I changed `lineHeight = 0.2`, and added underline, nice, but the selection control got be strange. The second, I used default `lineHeight`, but the underline is a bit far from text. So how to add an underline to text closely without selection problem?

I tested, find out this issue is because of `originX = 'left'`, and `originY = 'top'`, if `originX = 'center'` it's ok.

[image]

[image]

Comment: lineHeight directly affects controls box; it's basically `fontSize * lineHeight`. There's no built-in way to modify vertical offset of decoration line. But the line in your example is way too low and looks like a bug of some sort. Please make a simple jsfiddle showing this problem.

Comment: here it is - http://jsfiddle.net/hellomaya/5XCTt/1/, issue report in github is here - https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/835

Comment: So the lineHeight is not interpreted to be the height of text line, but more like a scale factor. Otherwise, fontSize * lineHeight is wrong to get control box height. This bug fixed in latest dev version.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code hope it will work better for you.

```
<input type="button" id="undrline" value="Underline" class="underline"  >

$("#undrline").click(function() {
alert("underline");
var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
if (!obj) return;
obj.setTextDecoration('underline');
canvas.renderAll();
});
```